# Getting different value in database based on choosen value

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

The users have the same login account but have different account numbers (one user can have multiple accounts), example:

1. ID : 1
2. User_id : 101
3. Email : kid@do.com
4. Account_number :30001
5. Name : Kiddo
6. Sex : Male
7. Income : 50000

---

1. ID : 2
2. User_id : 101
3. Email : kid@do.com
4. Account_number :30002
5. Name : Kiddo
6. Sex : Male
7. Income : 40000

As you can see, the only difference between the user accounts is the income and account number.

I have this simple form to show the user data based on the account number, when the user selects account number 30001 it will show the value above, and when the user selects account number 30002, the user will see the other value.

This is the example for select option:

```
<div class="form-group form-material">
            <label class="col-lg-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Account Number
            <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" id="noacc" name="noacc" required>
                @foreach($accounts as $key => $account)
                <option value="{{ $account->account_number}}" >{{ $account->account_number}}</option>   
                @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and this is the input form for income:

```
 <div class="form-group form-material">
            <label class="col-lg-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Income
            <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-9">
              <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="income" value="{{ $accounts->income }}">
            </div>
          </div>
```

But when the user changes the account number, the income value is still not changed.

Comment: you have to add onchange() when select any option and in that onchange() method you have to re-call data based on option selection, otherwise data won't be updated as you don't have any action after option choosen that's why data remain same as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be achieve without using Javascript or submitting a form. Because the form is already rendered with the HTML/value by the server. It can't dynamically changes the existing value.

Below are untested code, just the idea.

Method 1:

```
<script>
function setIncome(accNumber) {
  const accounts = @json($accounts->map(function($account) {
   return {
     "accountNumber": $account->accountNumber,
     "income": $account->income
   };})
  const income = accounts.find((account) => account.accountNumber === accNumber).income
  document.getElementById('incomeField').value = income;
)

}
</script>

<select onChange="setIncome"></select>
<input name="income" id="incomeField">
```

Method 2:
You submit a small form with selected `accountNumber`, then backend return the `$selectedAccountIncome`, then you field in to the incomeField.

Method 3:
Use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). Having a similar onChange function above but use the `accountNumber` to get the `income` and display on the frontend.